I have few genes and would like to retrieve their gene expression. Please any one help me how to retrieve the gene expression

How to retrieve the gene expression for the analyzing up and down regulations? .

In what context? What species? Expression in what tissue(s)? Under what conditions? What stage in development? What kind of data do you need, specifically? How expression varies over time? Highest expression level? Lowest? Tissue where the gene is most/least expressed? Please [edit] your question and explain what you need.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Based on these genes if I get the differentially expressed genes and their regulations I would like to know how many up regulation, down regulation and unclassified genes are present.

Please [edit] your question and add the details. But you need to explain: upregulated compared to what? Under what conditions? You cannot just be "upregulated" or "downregulated", you need something to compare with. It's like saying you want to find people who are "taller" but without saying taller than whom.

For a few genes you may just explore them in ENSEMBL, ENSEMBL AKT1
